# Custom list, moving stuff up automatically after removal in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scrollview

So im developing this app, where i got something that reminds alot about a list, but it doesn't use a list control or something. I add grids & rectangels to a scrollviewer, and when i doubletap a grip or a rectangel, it dissapears with a fade animation (which i also need help to do, as well as fade in, fast, one by one on app startup), and when that happens, i want the grid or rectangel beneath the one that faded out (or was removed, what is the best solution?), to be slided up, and replace the empty position. Please, do not misunderstand the question, i dont want you to make it for me, i want to know how since i absolutely cannot find ANY solution at all. It kind of works like google now for android and iphone. How can i do this the best way? Thank you SO much! Best regards, Erik

My DoubleAnimation to fade the grid:

```
        DoubleAnimation fadeGrid = new DoubleAnimation();
        fadeGrid.From = 0;
        fadeGrid.To = 1;
        fadeGrid.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
        fadeGrid.AutoReverse = false;
```

Comment: Make sure you enable Dependent Animations.

Comment: How do i enable dependent animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use animations for your fade out and slide up. For fade, you'll be doing a DoubleAnimation on the Opacity property. For sliding items up, you'll be doing an animiation on the TranslateTransform property.  See these MSDN guides: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206955(v=vs.105).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.translatetransform(v=vs.105).aspx

2) For actually properly moving things up, you'll want to capture the Completed event from the animiation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.105).aspx). When the animiation completes, remove those controls from the StackPanel inside the ScrollViewer, and undo any position animation you did on the items below it to animate them 'sliding' up.

3) After creating an animiation, you need to add it to a storyboard:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(fadeGrid);
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeGrid, myRectangle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeGrid, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Opacity)"));
sb.Begin();
```

The syntax for the propertypath but not be quite perfect, but you get the idea. You can see another example that specifically mentions opacity here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/03/21/silverlight-animations-a-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: first of all: thanks so much for help and answer! I actually created a doubleanimation to animate the opacityproperty, but i couldn't apply/run in on the grid, there was nothing like ".beginanimation" or similar. I'll post my doubleanimation

Comment: You need to add the animation to a storyboard, which you can then begin - I'll edit the answer with the example from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: so now i have managed to fade things, but when i remove a thing from the list, i have managed to fade it out, but then i really cant get the grid below to slide up, i really need some help with that. And also, a small question - since every grid in my selfmade list needs to be able to fade out on doubletap, is there any method for adding that functionality to all of the grids, or do i have to do it one by one?

Comment: For the first question - you need to capture the Completed event from the fade animation, and start a 2nd animation to slide the other controls up, by animating the Y property of the grid's TranslateTransform property. See the 2nd link in my 1st point in the answer for details on how the TranslateTransform animiation works. You'll need to start that animation for all grids below the one you're removing.

Comment: For the 2nd question - you can create a custom user control that contains your grid, and has storyboards for both animations created with it as resources in XAML, then add methods to start the animations. Some info on user controls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=VS.95%29.aspx and  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159446/Creating-and-Using-Reusing-User-Controls-in-Silver.

Comment: Thanks, i thiiinnnk i got it now:) I'll ask if it doesnt work